# How to decide for clustering columns in Cassandra primary key?

Tags: cassandra

I am following book 'Definitive Cassandra'. A hotel application is used as an example in it. THere is a table available_rooms_by_hotel_date. It is to support use case when user wants to know about room availability in a given hotel from a given date. Data model is defined as:

```
hotel_id
date
room_number
is_available
```

hotel_id is partition key, while date and room_number are clustering columns.

Looking at the table, one can say that it supports use case when user wants to know availability of room from a given date for a given hotel.

I understand that order of clustering columns is also critical in Cassandra. So if I change order for date and room_number, how would it impact? Functionality wise I think use case is still supported. But does it impact performance or any other aspects like storage, node allocation etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra you can query a table by:

1. the full primary key (`hotel_id`, `date`, `room_number`) - in this case you fetch only one row
2. the partition key (`hotel_id`) - in that case you get all rows inside given partition - it's a minimal requirement for `SELECT` query;
3. a partial primary key - partition key + some of the clustering columns, from left to right (**any preceding clustering columns defined in the primary key should be specified**). In the given example, you can specify only `hotel_id` and `date`, and it will return all rows for given date (or dates, if you do `date IN (...)`.  Another useful feature of the clustering column is that you can do a range query on it (*but only on the last specified clustering column*!).  For example, if I want to find all the rooms in a given date range, I can do `... WHERE hotel_id = ... AND date >= '2020-04-05' AND date <= '2020-04-10'`.

If you change the order of the `room_number` and `date`, then you could only ask for availability of the specific room(s) on date (or overall), not all rooms on specific dates - because you need to specify all preceding clustering columns, but you have only `hotel_id` and `date`, but not `room_number`...